# website is viewing as mobile, how do I turn this off?

Tags: mobile

I have just changed servers from a slow server to a faster server, and I notice that my website is now automatically showing as mobile view?  This has not happened before.  How do I turn this off or switch it back to normal website view?

I'm working in wordpress - theme:  Emporium
My website is:  www.atadesigns.com

Thank you for your help

Annette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is working perfectly fine for me.

You are using a responsive website, this means that the appearance of the site changes depending on how big your screen or browser window is. You probably had a too small browser window, if you just make it bigger it should look normal again.

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as correct then (You do this by clicking the tick on the left side)?